# Vue.js 3 - watching props in child component does not work if props comes with a member of array in parent component

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I am working with Vue.js 3. I got a problem, let us see the code first.

**Code**

*ChildComponent.vue*

```
<template>
<div>
  {{ modelValue }}
  <input v-model="resultString"/>
  <button @click="showModelValue">show model value</button>
</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {defineComponent, PropType, ref, watch} from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    modelValue: {
      type: Object as PropType<number>,
      required: true,
    }
  },
  emits:['update:modelValue'],
  setup(props) {
    const resultString = ref<string>("");
    watch(() => props.modelValue, (newVal:number, oldVal:number) => {
      if (newVal % 2 == 0) {
        resultString.value = 'even';
      } else {
        resultString.value = 'odd';
      }
    }, {deep: true});
    const showModelValue = () => {
      console.log(props.modelValue);
    }
    return { resultString, showModelValue }
  }
})
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

*ParentComponent.vue*

```
<template>
  <div class="main-container">
    <child-component v-model="test1" />
    <button @click="increaseTest1">increase test1</button>

    <hr/>
    Cannot use v-model within v-for!
    <!--
    <div v-for="(testNum, index) in test2">
      <child-component v-model="testNum" /> <button @click="increaseTest2(index)">increase test2</button>
    </div>
    -->
    <hr/>

    <div v-for="(testNumWrapper, index) in test3">
      <child-component v-model="testNumWrapper.val" /> <button @click="increaseTest3(index)">increase test3</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {defineComponent, onMounted, ref} from "vue";
import ChildComponent from "@/main/components/pc/ChildComponent.vue";
export default defineComponent({
  components: {ChildComponent},
  setup() {
    const test1 = ref<number>(1);
    const increaseTest1 = () => test1.value++;

    /*
    const test2 = ref<number[]>([3,1,4,1,5,9]);
    const increaseTest2 = (index:number) => test2.value[index]++;
    const updateTest2 = (e:any) => {
      console.log(e);
    };
    */

    const test3 = ref<{val:number}[]>([]);
    const increaseTest3 = (index:number) => test3.value[index].val++;

    onMounted(() => {
      // This triggers watch() in childComponent.
      test1.value = 4;

      // But these do NOT trigger watch() in childComponent.
      test3.value = [{val: 3},{val: 1},{val: 4},{val: 1},{val: 5},{val: 9}];
    });

    return {
      test1, increaseTest1,
      //test2, increaseTest2, updateTest2,
      test3, increaseTest3,
    }
  }
});
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

The above codes are modified for sharing my problem, let me explain.

The ChildComponent decides if the value of modelValue is odd or even, automatically.

The ParentComponent...

- binds a ref variable, `test1` to ChildComponent,
- tries to bind each primitive typed member of ref array variable, `test2` to ChildComponents but this is not compiled because v-model cannot be used within v-for, so that I commented out the code lines and try the next test,
- binds each non-primitive typed member of ref array variable, `test3` to ChildComponent.

And it initiates the variables in `onMounted()`.

However, I've found that `watch()` in ChildCompoent works fine for `test1` but not for `test3`. The `watch()` also does not work for `test3` when I push a value into `test3` or delete a value from `test3`. (It works when I click increase button.)

Please, show me a way to trigger the `watch()` function for `test3`.

Thank you.

Comment: If you push to an array, watch will not trigger, you could try to watch for modelValue.length instead, or replace ref by reactive

Comment: *v-model cannot be used within v-for* = not true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course the `watch` in child component is not triggered by pushing or deleting elements from the array. Child component is not watching whole array but just single element (it's `val` property).

If you push new element into the array, child component for that element does not exist yet. If you delete an element, the child component rendered for that element is destroyed immediately. Only thing that can trigger that `watch` is indeed mutation of the `val` property...

Problem with `test2` is that `testNum` is local temporary variable - instead of `v-model="testNum"`, use `v-model="test2[index]"`

Anyway your `ChildComponent.vue` does not need `watch` at all. Just use `computed`:

```js
const resultString = computed(() => props.modelValue % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd')
```

...and btw you should be using `key` with `v-for` - [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#maintaining-state-with-key)

Comment: Thank you for teaching me, the vue.js newbie. The solution for `test2` and the advise for using `key` with `v-for` are very helpful.

I solved  the problem with `test3` which is that the `watch()` of `ChildComponet` does not work for `push`ing value into array of `ParentComponent`, by putting same code as `watch()` into `onBeforeMount()` of `ChildComponent`.

Thank you!